# App crash if I try to open a fragment in an activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

every time I try to open my `fragment` in my `MainActivity.class` my app crashs.

**MainActivity.class**

```
/* Menu */
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.add_server:
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddServerFragment.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_refresh:
            myWebView.reload();
            return true;
        default:
            return true;
    }        
...
 public class AddServerFragment extends Fragment {

    public AddServerFragment(){

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_ip, container, false);

        Button btn_back, btn_add;
        final EditText server_ip, server_name;

        server_ip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_server_address);
        server_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_server_name);

         /* Back Button */
        btn_back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_back);
        btn_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        /* Add IP Button */
        btn_add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
        btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String new_server_ip = null, new_server_name = null;

                ArrayList<String> server_name_list = new ArrayList<String>();
                ArrayList<String> server_ip_list = new ArrayList<String>();

                new_server_ip = server_ip.getText().toString();
                server_ip_list.add(new_server_ip);

                new_server_name = server_name.getText().toString();
                server_name_list.add(new_server_name);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

My errorlog only say, I have to add the Fragment in my Manifest.xml as activity. But I know, I don't have to add it there.

**Errorlog**

```
11-14 15:22:05.935 18345-18345/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-14 15:22:05.935 18345-18345/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime: Process: de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview, PID: 18345
11-14 15:22:05.935 18345-18345/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview.MainActivity$AddServerFragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
11-14 15:22:05.935 18345-18345/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1794)
11-14 15:22:05.935 18345-18345/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1512)
11-14 15:22:05.935 18345-18345/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3917)
11-14 15:22:05.935 18345-18345/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3877)
11-14 15:22:05.935 18345-18345/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:784)
11-14 15:22:05.935 18345-18345/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4200)
11-14 15:22:05.935 18345-18345/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4168)
11-14 15:22:05.935 18345-18345/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime:     at de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:90)
11-14 15:22:05.935 18345-18345/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2908)
11-14 15:22:05.935 18345-18345/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:361)
11-14 15:22:05.935 18345-18345/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:147)
11-14 15:22:05.935 18345-18345/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:100)
11-14 15:22:05.935 18345-18345/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:621)
11-14 15:22:05.935 18345-18345/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:811)
11-14 15:22:05.935 18345-18345/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:153)
11-14 15:22:05.935 18345-18345/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:958)
11-14 15:22:05.935 18345-18345/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:948)
11-14 15:22:05.935 18345-18345/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:191)
11-14 15:22:05.935 18345-18345/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
11-14 15:22:05.935 18345-18345/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1145)
11-14 15:22:05.935 18345-18345/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3042)
11-14 15:22:05.935 18345-18345/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3879)
11-14 15:22:05.935 18345-18345/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
11-14 15:22:05.935 18345-18345/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-14 15:22:05.935 18345-18345/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
11-14 15:22:05.935 18345-18345/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
11-14 15:22:05.935 18345-18345/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-14 15:22:05.935 18345-18345/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
11-14 15:22:05.935 18345-18345/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**Edit**

My Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: You are inflating your fragment, therefore you have to get all the views using `rootView`. For instance `rootView.findViewById(R.id.edit_server_address);`

Comment: if the log says that is possibly because you forget to declare your activity in the manifest.

Comment: Thanks for your answere, where I have to add it?
You mean I have to at `rootView.findViewById(R.id....);
for all my edit_text and buttons?

Comment: And another thing, when I use fragments in Android, I initialize my controls (buttons, edittext, etc)  in the onActivityCreated() method

Answer (score 2):

```
Wrong with the above code:
```

**ERROR**     Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddServerFragment.class);
                startActivity(intent);

```
    Use the correct method for using fragment, you have used method for starting activity.
```

**AddServerFragment is Fragment not activity.**

For fragment to add in activity, you have to use the following approach:

In your activity,

XML code part in activity_main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Java Code Part in MainActivity.class:

```
    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }

        // Create an instance of AddServerFragment
        AddServerFragment firstFragment = new AddServerFragment();
        // if there are any extras
        firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

        // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but I really don't know where exactly to add this, can you invite me in a chat please?

Comment: please wait, i'll try,

Comment: @Sorrow91, now i have updated some code please check and tell me, what issue you're facing

Comment: So I added under my `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

But I get an error:
`Error:(96, 25) error: no suitable method found for add(int,MainActivity.AddServerFragment)
method FragmentTransaction.add(Fragment,String) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to Fragment)
method FragmentTransaction.add(int,Fragment) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; MainActivity.AddServerFragment cannot be converted to Fragment)`

Comment: also add xml code where fragment_container, in activity xml,

Comment: Yes added a in my LinearLayout: `android:id ="@+id/container"` (renamed it)

Comment: Is it right where I added the `if...` and how can I open my `fragment` with my `switch case`

Comment: main thing is that you should know how to add fragment in activity, therefore study the below link, then you'll find it easy to understand  and also get every method to add fragment and use it according to requirements: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Creating-and-Using-Fragments, http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Then you can also use switch case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95140/discussion-between-androider-and-sorrow91).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the activity declaration to your **manifest** file:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
</activity>
```

Comment: Added it before. And sorry for not responding yesterday, I need 20 rep points to chat...

Answer (score 0):

You cant use intent when you want open fragment.
You can try [FragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html).

Example:

```
public void getFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment mFragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

    if (mFragment == null) {
        mFragment = fragment;
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, mFragment)
                .commit();
    }
    if (mFragment != null) {
        mFragment = fragment;
        fm.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null)
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, mFragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
```